# Marshall G100RCD

Tags: amplifiers

I was wondering if I could use the Marshall five way foot switch with my Marshall G100RCD? I was going to get the standard pedal, but thought about the five way instead.

Comment: Perhaps there is a product forum, documentation download, or support page on the Marshall web site? Or you could ask the store where you are thinking of buying the footswitch from.

Comment: [The manual](http://preview.u-manual.com/preview-manual-for-free-274522/amplifier-marshall-mg50-80-100rcd.html?p=3) suggests not, it only takes a single footswitch via jack input.